# assign array index and values to input - Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am able to populate the input with name **collection**, however it appears as

```
collection : 0,1,2
```

How can make the collection look like

```
collection => 

 [0] => 0 
 [1] => 1
 [2] => 2
```

**file**

```
  <input type="hidden" name="collection"  />
  <input style="display:none" type="text" class="product-ids" name="product_ids[]" value="{{$product_id[$key]}}" />
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type="text"].product-ids').each(function () {

      total_product_id.push($(this).val());
      $('input[name="collection"]').val(total_product_id);
    });
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: Given that the input can contain only a single line of text, I don't see how the output you're expecting is achievable. Can you provide a HTML sample of the output you want to see.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  i have added an image of how i want to display

Comment: So by output you mean how you want to receive the values in what, I assume, is PHP?

Comment: Yes, it is PHP. In PHP,  i could explode to have this output. However, i would want to handle this in jquery. Not sure how to

Comment: I'm not a PHP dev, but I believe that to achieve this you need to create multiple `input` elements with the name `product_ids[]` and have a different value in each.

Comment: Can you share a sample on how to do this ? Just starting with jquery

Comment: Like answre of @RoryMcCrossan, you can create multiple inputs, which have name with suffix "[]".

I guess the backend you are using is Laravel, so you can retrieve these IDs by `request()->input('product_ids')`

Comment: `collection.split(",")` will give an array structure